# How to Use EF Core 2.2.4 Data Library With Asp.Net Core 2.1 Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to create a new Restful web api using Asp.Net Core 2.1 and I would like to use a shared data library to access the underlying data. The data library uses Entity Framework Core 2.2.4 and entity framework 6.1

There are other applications that reference this data library and it would be beneficial to have the web api also referencing the same project.

As soon as I add any code that references the dbContext I get the following error when trying to compile the web api:

Assembly 'data' with identity 'data uses 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.2.4.0  which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore' with identity 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'

Is what I'm trying to do even possible and if so can you please point me in the right direction

Comment: Have you tried updating the EF Core Reference in the Web Api to 2.2.4.0?

Comment: @TonyAbrams From what i can gather the reference to EF Core is within the Asp.net Core 2.1 Nuget package.and when I try and install the EF Core 2.2.4 package to the project it gives this error: Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1 requires Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 2.1.1 && < 2.2.0) but version Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.2.4 was resolved.

Comment: I guess this comes from the AspNetCore.All Package. You can remove it and add just the packages you need.

Comment: @Rabban Its contained within the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App Package and the uninstall button is greyed out and I can;t select a different version to install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of EF Core is tightly coupled with the version of ASP.NET Core you're using. Basically: EF Core 2.2.x only works on ASP.NET Core 2.2.x. You'll need to update the `TargetFramework` to `netcoreapp2.2` to make it work.

Also, the recommended way to reference ASP.NET Core (in .NET Core 2.x projects) is to not include a specific version:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
```

Instead of

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.1" />
```